# Are there any literary sources for the claim that light from below evokes fear in the viewer?

Tags: fear

It is sometimes stated that light from below or 'underlighting' can be used in movies to evoke fear in the viewer. I'm curious, are there any written sources for that claim? In filmmaking or film studies textbooks? Or even some academic studies?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Where you said *"It is sometimes stated..."* can you please provide an example or two?

Comment: Yes, sure! For example:
"Underlighting — Light shines from under the character’s face, creating a sinister and creepy effect." (https://thefilmpost.medium.com/cinematography-understanding-lighting-in-film-74641e56fd5b)
Also throughout this tutorial video: https://youtu.be/jPDBMYSGvSs
And of course it was also something that was mentioned a few times in film school.

Comment: Just a guess but light from below is not a very natural phenomenon. Just like recognizing faces upside-down etc.

Comment: Agreed. But still trying to find a study.